# Visa requirements to enter the UAE for a Portuguese citizen

Tags: visas, dubai, portuguese-citizens

I am a Portuguese citizen and I heard that there is no visa required for entering Dubai (United Arab Emirates.) I plan to book a return ticket and will exchange funds for my business trip to the UAE. Is there anything else I need to do? Do I need to fill any online form or similar? Or is it just simply booking the flight tickets and flying to Dubai?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, there is also the possibility of my spouse whose an Indian citizen accompanying me. We will be traveling from India if it helps. Our duration of stay in the UAE is for around 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

The United Arab Emirates has a **very easy visa policy** for citizens of the EU: just show up, nothing else needed.  You don't even need to fill out an immigration card.

You do need a passport valid for at least 6 months, and in theory funds sufficient for your stay and a return ticket, although I've never been asked for either.

Answer (score 1):

Book your ticket and enjoy your flight. Upon arrival you will be stamped into the country by the immigration officer.

Keep in mind the following restrictions:

- Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date.
- Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to passengers who stay less than 3 months must be valid for a minimum of 3 months from the arrival date.
- Passengers with a handwritten passport are not allowed to enter.
- Passengers with dual nationality must present the same passport at immigration upon entry and departure.
- Visitors with an extended validity in their passports are not allowed to enter.